# How to format http response into string array using spring rest template?

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

How do I store the response body into String array?

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String> response
            = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9100/metrics", String.class);
```

Here is my http response:

```
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the GC invocation durations.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 3.6951e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 7.3898e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0.000106166
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 0.000113714
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.000744301
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 0.001169959
```

I would like to store the above data in a String array so that I can remove the comments and process the data.

How do i convert the above response into a String array?

Answer (score 1):

Your response structure is not of type `String` array. It provides you strings possibly in new lines.  To capture the response in `String` array,  you need to change the response structure. Also, change the following line:

```
restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9100/metrics", String[].class);
```

Alternatively,  get the response as String and then parse it to eliminate comments. Tokenize data by `line separator` or the `separator` response data has and then store into a `String` array.

Answer (score 0):

List object = Arrays.asList(response.getBody().split("\r?\n"));